# SASS not showing in customized preloader plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, css, sass

I am new to WordPress and webdev in general so my skills are moderate.

I am using a plugin called WP Smart Preloader to build my sites preloader. It allows for the use of custom HTML and CSS. The HTML part of my preloader works but the styling does not show. My custom preloader is using SCSS which I think is causing the problem.

Is there any way to allow the use of SCSS in this plugin?

Here is my preloader on Codepen: https://codepen.io/wuhdotse/pen/jOWZwNM

And here is the customized preloader plugin: https://github.com/wuhdotse/preloader

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Browsers can’t parse SASS. It needs to be compiled into CSS to be usable. If this plugin doesn’t do that then you’d need to convert it to CSS.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you! I compiled it to CSS and now it works fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had to compile my SCSS to CSS using a compiler. I used this [online compiler](https://www.sassmeister.com/) but of course others will work as well.

Now everything works.